# How to specify non-trivial metadata to drive a shake build system?

Tags: configuration, shake-build-system

Given a non-homogeneously structured mixed-language code base, what is the recommended way to specify metadata to drive a Shake build system?

In particular, the metadata should describe source language (C++, C#, Fortran), source files, result type (static/dynamic lib, executable), compiler switches (potentially different for each artifact), etc.

Preferably, the metadata should be simply structured and stored in one separate file per artifact.

Is there a smart way to generalize the approach suggested in [Defining your own build system with Shake](http://ndmitchell.com/downloads/slides-defining_your_own_build_system_with_shake-09_oct_2015.pdf)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach from the presentation scales quite far - I've used it for huge multilanguage projects. I've used three tweaks beyond the talk:

#### Add file extensions

Typically file extensions give you the source language and result type. For example:

```
mycsharp.dll = foo.cs bar.cs
myfortran.exe = main.f90 util.f90
docs.pdf = docs.tex references.bib
```

Now you can have entirely different rules to interpret Fortran executables, C# executables (or dlls) and PDF documents.

#### Add some 'leading' characters

Often you want data about flags, or other command-line relevant data. For example:

```
mycsharp.dll = foo.cs bar.cs -define:DEBUG -optimize +mono
```

I tend to use special leading characters. In the above example I've used `-` to denote flags (which are usually passed on verbatim), and `+` to denote a selection from an enumeration which contains useful special cases (e.g. use the [mono compiler](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/languages/csharp/)).

One word of caution, don't use too many weird leading special characters, or you end up inventing your own language - keep it simple.

#### Use a C pre processor (CPP)

The C pre processor gives you `#include`, `#define` and `#ifdef`, all of which can be used in more complex structured metadata. You can use this with Shake by invoking [`cpphs`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cpphs) on the metadata file first.

While the two previous tweaks are recommended, the use of CPP was originally for `#include`. Now the built-in Shake metadata has an include mechanism I'm not sure I'd bother with CPP, which keeps things simpler.

Comment: Encoding metadata into variable names and using special characters to distinguish types of information are nice tweaks. Thanks!

Comment: Another technique that came to my mind is generating a Shake config file from custom config files distributed in the file system. In order to establish a better build system at my work place it would be helpful, I think, if at least during a transition phase these custom config files would be Visual Studio project files. Currently, the build is driven by some Python scripts and a bunch of Visual Studio solutions that contain about 500 projects. Do you think the general approach is feasible? I understand that it involves a non-negligible amount of work.

Comment: @precarious: That's exactly what we did it my work, but driven from Makefiles (since that was our original format) - see http://neilmitchell.blogspot.co.uk/2014/07/converting-make-to-shake.html. Originally we had a script that translated Makefile to custom configs which ran at the start of every build (just a Haskell script before even getting to Shake). To transition, we deleted the Makefiles and checked in the generated configs. It wasn't that much work as the parser/translator could be incredibly hacky and temporary, with special cases for anything weird.